# KeyError Using keras.utils.Sequence with keras.model.fit_generator

Tags: multithreading, queue, multiprocessing, keras

**Problem Statement:**

I'm trying to figure out how to use a [keras.utils.Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/) object with the [keras.model.fit_generator](https://keras.io/models/model/) function. My code is below.

**Code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!C:\Users\adam.hendry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python3.exe

# Imports

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import shutil
import glob
import scandir
import math
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event
import threading
import time
import csv
import pandas as pd

import keras

from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array

from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Lambda, Cropping2D
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

from keras import backend as k

import sklearn

# Global Variables

im_shape = (160, 320, 3)
batch_size = 64
num_epochs = 10
num_classes = 1
top_crop = 70
btm_crop = 25

root = r'C:\Users\adam.hendry\Desktop\CarND-Term1\Behavioral Cloning\training_data'

def get_model():

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x / 255.0 - 0.5, input_shape=im_shape))
    model.add(Cropping2D(cropping=((top_crop,btm_crop),(0,0))))
    model.add(Conv2D(24, (5,5), strides=(2,2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(36, (5,5), strides=(2,2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(48, (5,5), strides=(2,2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1164, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes))

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

    return model

def merge_csvs_into_df():

    out_df = pd.DataFrame()
    corr_factor = 0.1

    for path, folders, files in scandir.walk(root):

        for fldr in folders:

            for log_fl in glob.glob( os.path.join( path, fldr, '*.csv') ):

                df = pd.read_csv( log_fl, header=None, names=fieldnames )

                lft = df[['Left', 'Angle']]
                ctr = df[['Center', 'Angle']]
                rt = df[['Right', 'Angle']]

                lft['Angle'] += corr_factor
                rt['Angle'] -= corr_factor

                ctr.columns = ['img_pth', 'angle']
                lft.columns = ['img_pth', 'angle']
                rt.columns = ['img_pth', 'angle']

                out_df = out_df.append( ctr ).append( lft ).append( rt )

    return out_df

def get_data( split_frac = 0.2 ):

    train_frac = (1. - split_frac) ** 2
    val_frac = (1. - split_frac) * split_frac
    test_frac = split_frac

    df = merge_csvs_into_df()
    n_data = df.shape[0]

    ntrain = math.floor( train_frac * n_data )
    nval = math.floor( val_frac * n_data )
    ntest = math.floor( test_frac * n_data )

    df_train = df.iloc[:ntrain]
    df_val = df.iloc[ntrain:ntrain+nval]
    df_test = df.iloc[ntrain+nval:]

    return df_train, df_val, df_test

class DataSequence(keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__( self, df, batch_size = batch_size ):
        self.X = df.img_pth.values
        self.y = df.angle.values
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil( 1. * len( self.X ) / self.batch_size )

    def __getitem__(self, idx):

        batch_X = self.X[ idx * self.batch_size : (idx + 1) * self.batch_size ]
        batch_y = self.y[ idx * self.batch_size : (idx + 1) * self.batch_size ]

        X = np.array([ img_to_array( load_img( f, target_size=im_shape ) ) \
                       for f in batch_X ])

        y = np.array(batch_y)

        return X, y

class ThreadsafeIterator(object):

    def __init__(self, it):
        self.it = it
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        with self.lock:
            return next( self.it )

def threadsafe_generator( f ):

    def g(*a, **kw):
        return ThreadsafeIterator( f(*a, **kw) )
    return g

@threadsafe_generator
def generator_from_df( df, batch_size, shuffle = True ):

    nbatches, n_skipped_per_epoch = divmod( df.shape[0], batch_size )

    epoch = 0

    while True:

        if shuffle:
            # shuffle each epoch; use "tricky" `pandas.sample()` way
            df = df.sample( frac = 1 ) # frac=1 is same as shuffling df

        epoch += 1
        i, j = 0, batch_size

        mini_batches_completed = 0

        for _ in range( nbatches ):

            sub = df.iloc[i:j]

            X = np.array( [ img_to_array( load_img( f, target_size=im_shape ) ) \
                            for f in sub.img_pth.values ] )

            y = sub.angle.values

            mini_batches_completed += 1

            yield X, y

        i = j
        j += batch_size

def main(*args, **kargs):
    """ Behavioral Cloning Program
    """

    model = get_model()

    df_train, df_val, _ = get_data()

    ntrain, nval = df_train.shape[0], df_val.shape[0]

    train_sequence = DataSequence( df_train )
    val_generator = generator_from_df( df_val, batch_size, im_shape )

    nbatches_train, mod_train = divmod( ntrain, batch_size )
    nbatches_val, mod_val = divmod( nval, batch_size )

    if mod_train > 0:   nbatches_train += 1
    if mod_val > 0: nbatches_val += 1

    nworkers = mp.cpu_count()-1 or 1

    model.fit_generator(
        generator = train_sequence,
        steps_per_epoch = nbatches_train,
        epochs = num_epochs,
        validation_data = val_generator,
        validation_steps = nbatches_val,
        workers = nworkers,
        use_multiprocessing = True )

    model.save('model.h5')              

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ Entry point to the program
    """
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
    main()
```

**Question**

After python successfully starts all my threads, I get the following error. Can someone please provide solution? Any help would be appreciated.

**Error**

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adam.hendry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multipro
cessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\adam.hendry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pac
kages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 391, in get_index
    return _SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid][i]
KeyError: 0
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adam.hendry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pac
kages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 551, in get
    inputs = self.queue.get(block=True).get()
  File "C:\Users\adam.hendry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\multipro
cessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "behavioral_cloning_project_5.py", line 278, in <module>
    main()
  File "behavioral_cloning_project_5.py", line 270, in main
    use_multiprocessing = True )
  File "C:\Users\adam.hendry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pac
kages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\adam.hendry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pac
kages\keras\models.py", line 1227, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\adam.hendry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pac
kages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\adam.hendry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pac
kages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2115, in fit_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)
  File "C:\Users\adam.hendry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-pac
kages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 557, in get
    six.raise_from(StopIteration(e), e)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
StopIteration: 0
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I am having the same issue and can't debug it.

Comment: Got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

The same error happened with me, fixed it by using `int` instead of `math.ceil` in the `__len__` function. to make sure it's gonna work you can debug it by doing the following

```py
seq = DataSequence(""" pass parameters """)
l = len(seq)
last = seq[l-1] # try this now and if it gives you an error switch from math.ceil to int
```